# android material library crashes the app when using a password toggle drawable with TextInputLayout

Tags: android, material-design, androidx, android-textinputlayout

This is my TextInputLayout along with the InputEdit (login_dialog_layout exactly line 18 according to error):

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/passwordTextLayoutHolder"
        style="@style/TextInputLayoutOutlinedBoxStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_eye">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/txtLoginPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This is ic_eye:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M12,4.5C7,4.5 2.73,7.61 1,12c1.73,4.39 6,7.5 11,7.5s9.27,-3.11 11,-7.5c-1.73,-4.39 -6,-7.5 -11,-7.5zM12,17c-2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5s2.24,-5 5,-5 5,2.24 5,5 -2.24,5 -5,5zM12,9c-1.66,0 -3,1.34 -3,3s1.34,3 3,3 3,-1.34 3,-3 -1.34,-3 -3,-3z" />
</vector>
```

This is the style it is using:

```
 <style name="TextInputLayoutOutlinedBoxStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

My app theme is also correctly inheriting from "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight". No issues here.

But the app keeps crashing, after 3 hours of crawling and crawling I found out that the passwordToggleDrawable was the reason indeed, but not only this! In other layouts also if I use drawables along with Views like EditText and Buttons it will also crash.
I thought this might because of drawables-v21 and drawables-xhdpi (and other DPIs) so I removed all other folders and tried again but still no luck.

I have already migrated to Android X and using Android Material 1.2.0, I even tried the beta2 1.3.0 but no use.
I have tested on Marshmallow and Lollipop surprisingly there were no crashed so I am definitely sure that there is something that the app can't find when loading the drawables.

Also in my build.gardle (app) I have already added:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

This is the error I get:

```
    2020-09-03 01:33:01.514 6783-6783/org.zminic.ovido E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.zminic.ovido, PID: 6783
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in org.zminic.ovido:layout/login_dialog_layout: Binary XML file line #18 in org.zminic.ovido:layout/login_dialog_layout: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in org.zminic.ovido:layout/login_dialog_layout: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at org.zminic.ovido.activities.Login.showLoginWithEmailDialog(Login.kt:397)
        at org.zminic.ovido.activities.Login.access$showLoginWithEmailDialog(Login.kt:45)
        at org.zminic.ovido.activities.Login$onCreate$4.onClick(Login.kt:80)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in org.zminic.ovido:layout/design_text_input_end_icon: Binary XML file line #18 in org.zminic.ovido:layout/design_text_input_end_icon: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.internal.CheckableImageButton
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in org.zminic.ovido:layout/design_text_input_end_icon: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.internal.CheckableImageButton
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:596)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
2020-09-03 01:33:01.517 6783-6783/org.zminic.ovido E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at org.zminic.ovido.activities.Login.showLoginWithEmailDialog(Login.kt:397)
        at org.zminic.ovido.activities.Login.access$showLoginWithEmailDialog(Login.kt:45)
        at org.zminic.ovido.activities.Login$onCreate$4.onClick(Login.kt:80)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040005 a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:997)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:981)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5535)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:195)
        at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:86)
        at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:82)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:75)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.CheckableImageButton.<init>(CheckableImageButton.java:56)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.CheckableImageButton.<init>(CheckableImageButton.java:52)
```

Please help.

Comment: Post your @drawable/ic_eye

Comment: Did you override in your app theme attributes like `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` or `actionBarItemBackground`?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Nope..

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti... One thing that I have just discovered right now is by downgrading material and androidx.appcompat libraries the crash seems to be gone but now the passToggle drawable is also gone too.
So even by using passToggleDrawable or iconMode to pass_toggle I just see an empty textbox where every character just disappears into it.

Comment: Sorry, not able to reproduce. Just try the same layout in an empty project

Comment: Now check the app theme copying the attribute from the current project into the new.

Comment: Yep... Still works fine.. Seems that there is no problem with my styles.xml

Comment: I am suspicious that there is some error in drawable loading.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Thanks for the help sir. As a final resort I erased my entire res folder and stored back each and every file one by one rebuilding the project and inspecting the layout more than 200~ times even tho I haven't found something specific that caused the problem but I am sure whatever it was, it was inside the res folder. But now it sometimes work, and sometimes crash... -_______-